# SQL Server HAVING COUNT OVER issue

Tags: sql-server, count

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    x.CountryID [code], 
    c.Description [name],
    COUNT(x.username) OVER(PARTITION BY x.countryID) [count],
    COUNT(x.username) OVER () [tcount],
    COALESCE(c.Map,'world') [map]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CountryID, 
        username, 
        Score
    FROM global.dbo.UserCategories
    WHERE TLCID LIKE @TLCID OR TLCID IN (@TLCID)
) x
JOIN global.dbo.countrydetails c on x.CountryID=c.country
AND x.Score BETWEEN @ScoreMin AND @ScoreMax
GROUP BY x.CountryID, c.Description, c.Map, x.username --WITH ROLLUP
--HAVING COUNT(x.username) OVER(PARTITION BY x.countryID)>@Min
ORDER BY [name] ASC
```

that shows for every country the number of users having a certain score and active in certain categories
I would like to exclude from the list countries with few users
and I thought to add the HAVING clause
but sql tells me

> "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY
>   clauses."

the most important table is CountryDetails that looks like this:

```
CountryID   username    score       TLCID
    DE      12-bu       19598       131090
    DE      12-bu       19598       220
    DE      12-bu       19598       11700
    DE      12-bu       19598       131090
    DE      1buy3       19648       11700
    DE      1buy3       19648       11450
    DE      1buy3       19648       11700
    DE      1buy3       19648       11700
    CN      2012f       22780       11450
    CN      2012f       22780       11450
    CN      2012f       22780       11450
    CN      2012f       22780       11450
    CN      2012f       22780       11450
    GB      agood       74539       1
    GB      agood       74539       11450
    GB      agood       74539       12576
    GB      agood       74539       131090
    GB      agood       74539       1
    GB      agood       74539       11233
    GB      agood       74539       1
    GB      agood       74539       1
    GB      agood       74539       1
    GB      agood       74539       220
    BG      best0       3173        2984
    IT      bestb       13777       15032
    IT      bestb       13777       293
    IT      bestb       13777       293
    IT      bestb       13777       15032
    IT      bestb       13777       15032
    IT      bestb       13777       15032
    IT      bestb       13777       58058
    IT      bestb       13777       293
    DE      bestb       55165       131090
    DE      bestb       55165       293
    DE      bestb       55165       293
    DE      bestb       55165       293
    DE      bestb       55165       293
    CN      besto       24537       11450
    GB      bidan       4584        58058
    GB      bidan       4584        58058
    IT      bimbu       4145        11700
    GB      buy_d       97093       12576
    GB      buy_d       97093       888
    GB      buy_d       97093       888
    GB      buy_d       97093       888
    GB      buy_d       97093       159912
    GB      buy_d       97093       888
    GB      buy_d       97093       159912
    GB      buy_d       97093       11700
    GB      buy_d       97093       11700
    GB      buy_d       97093       159912
    GB      buy_d       97093       20710
    GB      buy_d       97093       159912
    GB      buy_d       97093       888
    GB      buy_s       988538      11232
    GB      buy_s       988538      1
    GB      buy_s       988538      11700
    GB      buy_s       988538      26395
```

concerning result.. now I get this

```
code    name        count       tcount  map
AD      Andorra         3       83141   andorra
AU      Australia       14      83141   australia
AT      Austria         345     83141   austria
.....
BE      Belgium         28      83141   belgium
CN      China           1070    83141   china
FR      France          4732    83141   france
DE      Germany         33782   83141   germany
HK      Hong Kong       364     83141   hongKong
HU      Hungary         9       83141   hungary
.....
IN      India           10      83141   india
IR      Iran            1       83141   iran
IQ      Iraq            17      83141   iraq
IE      Ireland         36      83141   ireland
IL      Israel          16      83141   israel
IT      Italy           5427    83141   italy
JE      Jersey          25      83141   world
....
GB      United Kingdom  35136   83141   unitedKingdom
```

....

assuming to set @Min to 20 I want to get this:

```
code    name            count   tcount  map
AT      Austria         345     80945   austria
BE      Belgium         28      80945   belgium
CN      China           1070    80945   china
FR      France          4732    80945   france
DE      Germany         33782   80945   germany
HK      Hong Kong       364     80945   hongKong
IE      Ireland         36      80945   ireland
IT      Italy           5427    80945   italy
JE      Jersey          25      80945   world
GB      United Kingdom  35136   80945   unitedKingdom
```

where tcount is the sum of count

Can Pls suggest the path for a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `HAVING [count] > @Min`? Not sure though, can't try it myself right now.

Comment: yes, tried, but (I suppose) since [count] is a calculated fields inside the query cannot be used as parameter

Comment: Because `x.CountryId` appears in the GROUP BY you do not need to partition by this.  The HAVING works at the same level as the group.  In this case it will count number of records within the unique combinations of `CountryId, Description, Map, Username`.

Comment: If you can add some sample records and expected output it will easier to see what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be able to do something as simple as this..

```
SELECT  c.countryid,
        c.[description],
        x.[count],
        SUM([count]) OVER () [tcount],
        COALESCE(c.Map,'world') [map]
FROM    global.dbo.countrydetails c
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT uc.username) [count]
            FROM    global.dbo.UserCategories uc
            WHERE   uc.countryid = c.countryid
                    AND TLCID LIKE @TLCID OR TLCID IN (@TLCID)
                    AND uc.Score BETWEEN @ScoreMin AND @ScoreMax
        ) x
WHERE   x.[count] > @Min
```

it will select the individual username counts and apply them to the countries.. then you can sum the counts to get tcount and filter on the individual counts

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/806ed/1)

Comment: hmmm.. yes.. it seems that (again!) outer apply is the solution..
will make some further test and let you know!

Comment: `Cross Apply` might give you better results since you're filtering on the results in the `Where` so i'd try both

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pretty close here. I think you were making it more complicated than it needs to be. Also, your where clause in the subselect is not quite right. It can be simplified to equals.

This should be pretty close.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    x.CountryID [code], 
    c.Description [name],
    COUNT(x.username) as [tcount],
    COALESCE(c.Map,'world') [map]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CountryID, 
        username, 
        Score
    FROM global.dbo.UserCategories
    WHERE TLCID = @TLCID
) x
JOIN global.dbo.countrydetails c on x.CountryID=c.country
AND x.Score BETWEEN @ScoreMin AND @ScoreMax
GROUP BY x.CountryID, c.Description, c.Map
HAVING COUNT(x.username) > @Min
ORDER BY [name] ASC
```

--EDIT--

It is challenging to figure out what you want because we have no tables, no sample data and no desired output. In short the best anybody can do right now it guess what you might want. This is a good article that explains what you should post for t-sql help on online forums. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Here is another guess at what you might want. I noticed you have distinct and group by. This is redundant.

```
with CompiledValues as
(
    SELECT x.CountryID as [code], 
        c.Description as [name],
        COUNT(x.username) OVER(PARTITION BY x.countryID) as [count],
        COUNT(x.username) OVER () as [tcount],
        COALESCE(c.Map,'world') [map]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            CountryID, 
            username
        FROM global.dbo.UserCategories
        WHERE TLCID = @TLCID
    ) x
    JOIN global.dbo.countrydetails c on x.CountryID = c.country
        AND x.Score BETWEEN @ScoreMin AND @ScoreMax
    GROUP BY x.CountryID
        , c.Description
        , c.Map
)

select *
from CompiledValues
where tcount > @Min
ORDER BY [name] ASC
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for answering, yes this solves the HAVING issue but you removed me the [tcount] field (you renamed [count] to [tcount]). in [tcount] i had the total number of user of all countries, and I cannot wait the end of the loop to calculate since I need to know in advance since it is used for some calculations

Comment: yes, you're right.. but since data was quite complex this time I thought to avoid but has not been a good idea.. just added some

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to make this determination when you select country / username.  Question is if a user can have > 1 score and if you want this part of determining your threshold count.

```
-- Filtering by Count of CountryID, username, Score
SELECT DISTINCT
    x.CountryID [code], 
    c.Description [name],
    COUNT(x.username) OVER(PARTITION BY x.countryID) [count],
    COUNT(x.username) OVER () [tcount],
    COALESCE(c.Map,'world') [map]
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*), 
        CountryID, 
        username, 
        Score
    FROM global.dbo.UserCategories
    WHERE TLCID LIKE @TLCID OR TLCID IN (@TLCID)
    GROUP BY CountryID, 
        username, 
        Score
    HAVING COUNT(*) > [Your_Threshold_Number]
) x
JOIN global.dbo.countrydetails c on x.CountryID=c.country
AND x.Score BETWEEN @ScoreMin AND @ScoreMax
GROUP BY x.CountryID, c.Description, c.Map, x.username
ORDER BY [name] ASC

-- Filtering by Count of CountryID, username
SELECT DISTINCT
    x.CountryID [code], 
    c.Description [name],
    COUNT(x.username) OVER(PARTITION BY x.countryID) [count],
    COUNT(x.username) OVER () [tcount],
    COALESCE(c.Map,'world') [map]
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*), 
        CountryID, 
        username, 
        Score
    FROM global.dbo.UserCategories AS g1
    JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt, 
        CountryID, 
        username
    FROM global.dbo.UserCategories
    GROUP BY CountryID, 
        username
    HAVING COUNT(*) > [Your_Threshold_Number]
    ) g2 ON g1.CountryID = g2.CountryID
    WHERE TLCID LIKE @TLCID OR TLCID IN (@TLCID)
    GROUP BY CountryID, 
        username, 
        Score
) x
JOIN global.dbo.countrydetails c on x.CountryID=c.country
AND x.Score BETWEEN @ScoreMin AND @ScoreMax
GROUP BY x.CountryID, c.Description, c.Map, x.username
ORDER BY [name] ASC
```